# www json api response to string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on an app in unity3d which is using a tmdb api for an application that allow the user to search for a movie and then display it in the text area, the problem I am having is that the data is being fetched in JSON format and I am very much confused as there are ways given on internet to parse it, but none of them are using www request thing instead they are reading file and then passing it to a string.Thank You!

[image: code]

Comment: So what did you tried so far? Show your code....without seeing your code how we can help you?

Comment: There are two separate steps here: 1) Obtaining the JSON as a string, whether that's from the web or a file. 2) Parsing the JSON. It sounds like you have plenty of examples of step 2 - so have you worked out step 1 yet?

Comment: I have tried some different different pieces of codes that resulted in some total blunders as I am a beginner to unity and JSON, not I am at the step one first I want to get the JSON as string, can you please show me the code for both the steps this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @AbrarIqbal SO is not here to provide tutorials - hence people want to know what you tried.  There are a number of examples of getting  json in unity, whether you read it from file, a URL or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to write class to serialize response json object.

In this case, this api returns json like this:

```
{
  "page": int,
  "total_results": int,
  "total_pages": int,
  "results": [
    {
      "vote_count": int,
      "id": int,
      "video": bool,
      "vote_average": float,
      "title": string,
      "popularity": double,
      "poster_path": string,
      "original_language": string,
      "original_title": string,
      "genre_ids": [
        int
      ],
      "backdrop_path": string,
      "adult": bool,
      "overview": string,
      "release_date": string
    }
  ]
}
```

So your Serializable class(es) should look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Movies
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int total_results { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public int vote_count { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool video { get; set; }
    public double vote_average { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public double popularity { get; set; }
    public string poster_path { get; set; }
    public string original_language { get; set; }
    public string original_title { get; set; }
    public IList<int> genre_ids { get; set; }
    public string backdrop_path { get; set; }
    public bool adult { get; set; }
    public string overview { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
}
```

After that you can easily deserialize json object, Here is an example code:

```
IEnumerator FetchMovies(string movieName)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url+"search/movie?api_key="+apiKey+"&query="+movieName);

    yield return www;

    if(www.error==null)
    {
        var movies = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movies>(www.text);

        foreach(var movie in movies.results)
        {
            Debug.Log("Title " + movie.title);
            Debug.Log("Overview " + movie.overview);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError(www.error);
    }
}
```